# Why does NetHogs report 0 KB/second while benchmarking lo?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, nc

I was curious to know how much traffic the Linux kernel could handle on the loopback network, so I decided to benchmark it. In one terminal, I ran:

```
% nc -l -p 5235 127.0.0.1 > /dev/null
```

And in another I ran:

```
% nc 127.0.0.1 5235 < /dev/zero
```

Then to actually measure traffic I ran `sudo nethogs lo`. This shows an entry for the second `nc` showing that it sends about 570,000 KB/second (on average). The first `nc` seems to send about 1,300 KB/second on average, which I assume is TCP control packets. However, both `nc` processes show 0 KB/second received. Why is this? It seems like each process should report a received value equal to the other's sent value.

Version information:

```
% nethogs -V
 version 0.8.1

% uname -a
Linux file-not-regular.strugee.net 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

% nc -h |& head -1
[v1.10-41]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the kernel doesn't really distinguish between inbound and outbound traffic beyond the source and destination IP addresses. The packets don't get "double-counted" because the kernel looks at the source IP, sees that it's local, classifies it as outbound, and doesn't bother classifying the packet any further (e.g. as inbound).

Comment: does this mean there is anything wrong in the network? I am having the same issue with nethogs. It shows 0 KB.

Comment: @user9371654 what do you mean "wrong with the network"? you mean the kernel's networking subsystem? if so, it depends on how you define "wrong". can you clarify?